# Magento shopping cart

Tags: magento

I use own template for my eshop but on my website I use currency € not $. Where can I edit it. http://i50.tinypic.com/67rvhc.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to System>Configuration.

Then in GENERAL>Currency setup you can change the currency.

Comment: Yes I have it. But this object isnt change.

Comment: Maybe you haven't flushed the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Configuration.

Then in GENERAL > Currency Setup

Set following--->

Base Currency: euro

Default Display Currency: euro

Allowed Currencies : euro

Save config.